# Flutter InteractiveViewer not panning/scrolling

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

```dart
InteractiveViewer(
  child: FlutterLogo(size: 1000),
)
```

`FlutterLogo` is bigger than the viewport and thus I wrapped it inside `InteractiveViewer` but it is not panning. I checked `panEnabled` and it is `true` by default. What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your widget is greater than viewport, you'll need to set `constrained` to `false`.

> [constrained](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/InteractiveViewer/constrained.html): If set to false, then the child will be given infinite constraints. This is often useful when a child should be bigger than the InteractiveViewer.

```dart
InteractiveViewer(
  constrained: false, // Set it to false
  child: FlutterLogo(size: 1000),
)
```